# Laravel, PHP 7.3 nginx 502 upstream prematurely closed FastCGI stdout

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I have a laravel application behind nginx and recently updated php from version 7.1 to 7.3 (docker image 7.1-fpm-alpine to 7.3-fpm-alpine).

I use exceptions that have a `render()` function to output error pages. Laravel logs the exception message and complete stacktrace.

Since updating to php 7.3, nginx shows it's default 502 error page and logs `[error] 11#11: *61 upstream prematurely closed FastCGI stdout while reading response header from upstream, client: [...]`. The stacktrace in nginx is truncated after 2048 bytes.

The serverfault question ["Nginx/PHP-FPM long log lines get truncated"](https://serverfault.com/questions/256459/nginx-php-fpm-long-log-lines-get-truncated) suggests that nginx handles only errors up to 2048 bytes.

In PHP 7.1 the stacktrace was truncated already.

Am I right, that the problem is that PHP now logs the complete stack trace instead of truncating it?

Is there a way to truncate log output in PHP to return to the behaviour of PHP 7.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My app uses `errorlog` log driver, and I came across the same problem. In Laravel, I modified `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` in the following way (much inspired by your question, actually):

```php
public function report(Exception $exception)
{
    $message = get_class($exception) . ": {$exception->getMessage()}. Trace:\n{$exception->getTraceAsString()}";
    error_log(substr($message, 0, 2048));
}
```

The substr() part is what does the trick. I still have to develop a nicer and more universal solution though, cuz this is just a quick-n-dirty fix.

Comment: Seems like a good workaround, thanks for the answer. I'll mark it as accepted if there is no better solution in a while.

Comment: It'd be great if you could update your answer if you've found a better solution.

Answer (score 6):

By default, PHP 7.3 should function the same as previous versions (it will truncate at 1024 characters), but there is [new configuration to allow more characters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php):

> log_limit integer
>   Log limit for the logged lines which allows to log messages longer than 1024 characters without wrapping. Default value: 1024. Available as of PHP 7.3.0.

---

I had this issue when using the official Docker PHP 7.3 container, which is specifically overwriting the default in the [`Dockerfile`](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/5992cb02fa5b3d76baffad60d94052a805958553/7.3/alpine3.10/fpm/Dockerfile#L208):

```
echo 'log_limit = 8192';
```

It can be fixed by overriding `log_limit` so it falls under nginx's limit of 2048:

```
[global]
log_limit = 1024
```

Comment: Relevant bit from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19084625/2532203): "**You need to recompile Nginx if you want log lines longer than 2048 bytes.**"
So it is not usually possible in a Docker environment to modify this limit, hence overriding the log limit as per your answer is pretty much required.